# The same SQL runs at very different speed in two databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a SQL Server database installed in a windows server. There is a database with name A, who has been running for years. And today, we create a backup image based on the latest A data, and restore a new database from the image, with name B.

Here is the SQL.

```
SELECT 
    ID, FileName AS imageurl 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [AGE], ID) AS rn,
         *
     FROM 
         T t
     WHERE 
         LEN(FileName) > 0 
         AND id <> 0 
         AND DateCreated > GETDATE() - 365) AS t
WHERE 
    t.rn = 1
```

There are almost the same data amount in A and B, because B is cloned from A. There are around 140000000 rows in this T table.

The same SQL, it runs very slow in database A, but fast in database B. They are in the same SQL Server and same windows server, and since B is cloned from A, they are almost the same. But why the speed differs?

Comment: Try `ALTER INDEX ALL ON myTable REORGANIZE` then `UPDATE STATISTICS myTable` on the slow DB. Ensure both databases have the same indexes defined for your table.

Comment: hi Robin, a new install will automatically Update Statistics whereas the old database may not have had this done recently and so runs slower. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Also have a look at the logs

Comment: Are the database mdf/ndf/ldf files residing on the same physical volume(s)? Maybe the restored database B is on faster HDD/SSD volumes than database A.

Comment: Loads of reasons... inspect the execution plan to find out...

Comment: Did this query is executed from the same client app ?

Comment: @JonP, A is a live database and there are many jobs connecting it and running on it. B is a dev database and no jobs running on it. This may be the reason. If there are a lot updating and reading operation on A in jobs, does it affect the select query speed?

Comment: @Robin Every SQL command adds a record in the log (so that it can recover in case of a crash) and does not update commonly used statistics. UPDATE STATISTICS can speed up select query speeds but has a one off penalty as it requires all your stored procedures to recompile. If you are doing a lot of updates and inserts see if the log files are huge, if they are this causes performance issues on selects. If yes try backing up your database and doing a truncate on the logs.